# elasticsearch query help - dont find documents

Tags: php, elasticsearch

i have a lot of documents indexed in elasticsearch. Now i create a query that found alot of documents - but they doesnt found document-names like this: "hello + friend"
if i search for hello - they found the document but if search for the real file.name "hello + friend" they doesnt found it.... What is with my query wrong? The same is for files in other languages like chineses.

Thanks for help

```
            $params = [
            'index' => 'search_dokumentation',
            'type' => 'document',
            'size' => 500,
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => [
                            'wildcard' => [
                                'file.name' => '*' . strtolower($searchTerm) . '*',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'minimum_should_match' => 1,
                    ],
                ],
                'sort' => [
                    '_score' => [
                        'order' => 'asc',
                    ],
                ],
            ],

"mappings": {
```

> ```
>   "meta": {
>     "_all": {
>       "enabled": false
>     },
>     "properties": {
>       "last_modified": {
>         "type": "date",
>         "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
>       },
>       "update_date": {
>         "type": "text",
>         "fields": {
>           "keyword": {
>             "type": "keyword",
>             "ignore_above": 256
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   },
>   "document": {
>     "_all": {
>       "enabled": false
>     },
>     "_source": {
>       "excludes": [
>         "file.content_base64"
>       ]
>     },
>     "properties": {
>       "article": {
>         "properties": {
>           "number": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           }
>         }
>       },
>       "file": {
>         "properties": {
>           "content_base64": {
>             "type": "text"
>           },
>           "create_date": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "created": {
>             "type": "date",
>             "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
>           },
>           "extension": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           },
>           "last_accessed": {
>             "type": "date",
>             "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
>           },
>           "last_modified": {
>             "type": "date",
>             "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
>           },
>           "link_file": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           },
>           "link_folder": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "name": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "decompound": {
>                 "type": "text",
>                 "analyzer": "my_decompound"
>               },
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               },
>               "simple": {
>                 "type": "text",
>                 "analyzer": "simple"
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "path_file": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           },
>           "path_folder": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           },
>           "path_folder_short": {
>             "type": "keyword"
>           },
>           "permissions": {
>             "type": "long"
>           },
>           "size": {
>             "type": "long"
>           },
>           "version": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       },
>       "relation": {
>         "properties": {
>           "machine": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "plant": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           },
>           "type": {
>             "type": "text",
>             "fields": {
>               "keyword": {
>                 "type": "keyword",
>                 "ignore_above": 256
>               }
>             }
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Have you tried any other query types? Like a `match` or `query_string`?

Comment: @Tim yes i have... i dont become a result when i search with special characters

Answer (score 0):

From your mapping, it looks like you're using the [`standard analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) for `file.name`. So a `match` query should work for you. Here's an example:

```
PUT newindex/_doc/1
{
  "file.name": "hello + friend"
}

GET newindex/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "file.name": "hello + friend"
    }
  }
}
```

The `standard analyzer` will actually remove the special characters. So if you `_analyze` the term "hello + friend" you'll see it splits it into two terms.

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["hello + friend"],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "hello",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "friend",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**EDIT:**

For the use case of matching the filename "Betriebsanleitung_Schere + Stangenmagazin_V3.5.pdf" with a partial match (the term "strange"), you can use the `query_string` with some wildcards.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*stangen*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for your answer. So i test it now and see does it works - but now i am confused for my query in PHP?

Comment: @se88 - I would update the query to match the [`match` documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html#_match_query).

Comment: He finds now only documents which are with whitespace between the words. So documents like: "this_is_a-test-file-9483.pdf" he does not find anymore? and the document "hello + friend" doesnt not find...

Comment: What is your use case? Are you looking for exact matches?

Comment: 'query' => [
                        'match' => [
                            'file.name' => strtolower($searchTerm),
                        ],
                    ],
for this usecase i dont want a exact match.... when i search for the file: "this_is_a-test-file-9483.pdf" and i write: "is a test" - then i must it see in the results

Comment: I get a result when I run your query. You can remove the `strtolower()` as the standard analyzer will take care of that for you.

Comment: doesnt work.. look my response: `array(4) { ["took"]=> int(1) ["timed_out"]=> bool(false) ["shards"]=> array(3) { ["total"]=> int(1) ["successful"]=> int(1) ["failed"]=> int(0) } ["hits"]=> array(3) { ["total"]=> int(0) ["max_score"]=> NULL ["hits"]=> array(0) { } } }` and i search for "stangen" and the filename is: "Betriebsanleitung_Schere + Stangenmagazin_V3.5.pdf" is it maybe better when i remove the "_" bevor i index the document? what i make wrong?